# Como executar uma procedure em um select?

Tags: sql, sql-server

O que eu tentei foi o seguinte, e minha procedure retorna apenas um select:

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        t_usuarios
    WHERE
        nome like '%jeniffer%'
    AND
        cd_usuario IN (exec usp_lista_emprestimo_em_atraso)
    ORDER BY
        nome
```

Alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 1):

Não é permitida a utilização de stored procedures em conjunto com as instruções SELECT, WHERE ou HAVING.

Posso sugerir uma alternativa. Crias uma tabela temporária para guardar o output da stored procedure e depois usas essa tabela na tua query.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#emprestimoAtraso') is not null
   drop table #emprestimosAtraso

create table #emprestimosAtraso(

   cd_usuario       int -- alterar de acordo com o output da stored procedure

)

insert into #emprestimosAtraso(cd_usuario)
exec usp_lista_emprestimo_em_atraso

select *
from  t_usuarios tbl_u
inner join #emprestimosAtraso tbl_e
   on tbl_e.cd_usuario = tbl_u.cd_usuario
where nome like '%jeniffer%'
order by nome
```

Outra alternativa passa por criar uma [função](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214485%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) equivalente á tua stored procedure que retorne uma tabela. Ao contrário das stored procedures, as funções podem ser utilizadas em conjunto com a instrução SELECT.

Com uma função a syntax ficaria, por exemplo, assim:

```
select *
from  t_usuarios tbl_u
inner join udf_emprestimosAtraso() udf_e
   on udf_e.cd_usuario = tbl_u.cd_usuario
where nome like '%jeniffer%'
order by nome
```

Comment: Vlw, mas eu resolvi de outro jeito, fiz uma view, dai fiz um select na view com as condições que eu queria!